# How does the request.timeout.ms of producer config and request.timeout.ms of broker config play together

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to understand the request timeout mechanism from the producer end. Let's say I have below configurations set

```
Producer Configurations:
delivery.timeout.ms = 15000
request.timeout.ms = 10000 
linger.ms = 0
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50

Broker configurations:
request.timeout.ms = 30000
```

Now, if I send a message at time `t1` and the cluster is down, how long does the producer wait before throwing connection exception?

Comment: Check out KIP-91 [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-91+Provide+Intuitive+User+Timeouts+in+The+Producer] that tells the story (with pictures!) and current state of affairs wrt producer timeouts.

Comment: sure, Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a test and observed that send() is failing with below exception

Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test.topic not present in metadata after 45000 ms

in this 45000 ms is the 'max.block.ms'.